# Some information about the JDBC logic in Spring Framework application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am learning how to use JDBC inside Spring application but I have some doubt about it.

So, let me explain my doubts about a practial example:

If I have a class that implements my DAO interface and this class contains the following method that insert a new row in a Student table of my database:

```
public void create(String name, Integer age) {
    String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";

    jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, name, age);
    System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
    return;
}
```

This method have 2 input parameter: **name** and **age** that are related to two column in my database table (NAME and AGE)

Ok...I think that the SQL string rappresent my SQL query that have to be executed to insert the new row in my table

I have some problem to understand what exactly means this piecce of code: **values(?, ?)**

I think that when I call the update() method on a JdbcTemplate object passing to it the SQL query and the **name** and **age* value these ? placeholder are replaced with these value.

So the query can be executed.

Is it right?

Is it the update() method that replace these placeholder?

I have also read that these placeholder are used so I don't have to worry about escaping my values...what exactly means **escape a value** ?

And the last question is about the use of **PreparedStatment**...reading the Spring documentation I have read that I can pass also a PreparedStatment to the update() method...what is the difference? in this case is Spring that create a new PreparedStatment using the SQL string and the 2 input parameter or am I using something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is mainly to avoid SQL injection.

If you just did this:

```
"insert into Student (name, age) values ('"+name+"', "+age+")"
```

Consider what would happen if `name` is `"mary', 3), ('john', 13)--"`

The query becomes:

```
insert into Student (name, age) values ('mary', 3), ('john', 13)--', 24)
```

And when you ignore the SQL comment `--`:

```
insert into Student (name, age) values ('mary', 3), ('john', 13)
```

2 records would be inserted.

You can of course escape or filter the name string, but that is error prone and it's easy to
forget and leave some query vulnerable, might as well use prepared statements to make this impossible.

Escaping means prepending an escape character before any SQL meta character so that its meaning
changes.

If you escaped the name, the query would be:

```
insert into Student (name, age) values ('\', 3), (\'john\', 13)--', 24)
```

I.E the name would literally be `"', 3), ('john', 13)--"` and no SQL injection happened.

Comment: It's not only to prevent SQL injection. It also improves performance (how much depends on the DBMS though)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I didn't say that was the case at all - I just said that it's the main purpose.

Comment: @AndreaNobili The `update()` method does indeed replace the `?`s with the values you pass into the method. And it uses a `PreparedStatement` behind the scenes.